# Button object in Qlik Sense

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

How can I use a button object in Qlik sense the same way it is in Qlikview? Qlik Sense has no button object in the default objects as it is in Qlikview.

Thanks in advance!
Ziad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently within QlikSense, however extensions can be used to add more functionality.

How to add extensions
https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-7033

Where to find extensions
http://branch.qlik.com/

This extension may be what you are looking for
http://branch.qlik.com/#/project/570663af9a200590510ae281

Comment: Hi Chris,

Thanks for your reply. I will check them all.

Answer (score 3):

there is a link for extension which enables you the option of downloading the extensions for qliksense. There by u can create the buttons like qlik view. Follow the steps as the link tells you.
http://branch.qlik.com/?&_ga=1.205648019.1497078496.1393695932#!/project/56728f52d1e497241ae698a0

Comment: Link only answers are not preferred on [so]. This is because they can become broken over time; consider encapsulating the advice from the link into a full answer of your own?

Comment: It sounds interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

have a look at https://github.com/stefanwalther/sense-navigation
This solution not only allows you to add a button to your sheet, but also to selection from a variety of actions like:

- gotoNextSheet
- gotoPrevSheet
- Set variable value
- open website
- ...

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Although the question is quite old, it is worth noting that buttons are now part of standard Qlik Sense charts.